# Two autocomplete, on two inputs (differnet id), on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

So I have two textfields on my page, img and lok. I want them both to have a autocomplete with data from another page that uses input-value as search string. The script that comes first in code works as it should. The next is never executed. If I changes order it works for the other input, so both works by them self. So I will have to make some function name to make them different? Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
            $("#img").autocomplete({
                minLength: 3,
                source: function (request, response) { 
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "q/qfolder.php", 
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data: {
                            q: $("#img").val(),  
                        }, 
                        success: function (data) { 
                            response(data); 
                        } 
                    }); 
                },
            })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item);
            };
        });
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
            $("#lok").autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: function (request, response) { 
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "q/qlok.php", 
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data: {
                            q: $("#lok").val(),  
                        }, 
                        success: function (data) { 
                            response(data);
                        } 
                    }); 
                },
            })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item);
            };
        });
</script>

<input type="text" id="lok">
<input type="text" id="img">
```

The JSONs is one dimentional, so quiet simple responses. Have read a lot of treads that was quite similar, but none resolved my problem. Sadly I have very little experience with jQuery.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle ?

Comment: will have to edit upload some files to search. hang on...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c4fwycfm/ cant get it to work at all in the fiddle, but you at least have something to play with, with links that works as they should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/c4fwycfm/2/

1. remove  .data("autocomplete") before ._renderItem
2. for otpion data use this data: { q: request.term },

**JQ:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#lok").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
    })
        ._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item);
    };
});

$(function () {
    $("#img").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
    })
        ._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            SearchImg();
            SearchLok();

            function SearchImg() {
            $("#img").autocomplete({
                minLength: 3,
                source: function (request, response) { 
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "q/qfolder.php", 
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data: {
                            q: $("#img").val(),  
                        }, 
                        success: function (data) { 
                            response(data); 
                        } 
                    }); 
                },
            })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item);
            };
        }

function SearchLok(){

$("#lok").autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: function (request, response) { 
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "q/qlok.php", 
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data: {
                            q: $("#lok").val(),  
                        }, 
                        success: function (data) { 
                            response(data);
                        } 
                    }); 
                },
            })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item);
            };

}

        });
```

Comment: What's the point of making the two autocomplete initializers two functions if you don't refactor them in the process?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working either. Thanks for the effort though!