# how to write different id for typeahead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I am using rails and elasticsearch and typeahead.

I have three inputs: company, position and navigation(search both for company and position).

I know how to implement one of them but don't know how to implement all of them while following DRY. How should I design the routes for autocomplete, the controller and js file?

Here is the code that works for one.

```
var numbers = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: "autocomplete?search=%QUERY",
    wildcard: "%QUERY"
  }
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
numbers.initialize();

$("#nav_search").typeahead({
  items: 6,
  source:numbers.ttAdapter()
});
$("#company_search").typeahead({
  items: 6,
  source:numbers.ttAdapter()
});
$("#position_search").typeahead({
  items: 6,
  source:numbers.ttAdapter()
});
```

Comment: I looked at this one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203423/two-autocomplete-on-two-inputs-differnet-id-on-same-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203423/two-autocomplete-on-two-inputs-differnet-id-on-same-page) but there are too many duplicate code.

Comment: I finally solved the problem using typeahead's replace function. Reference: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117476/bootstrap-3-typeahead-js-remote-url-attributes)
[2](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete/issues/16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite

```
$("#nav_search").typeahead({
  items: 6,
  source:numbers.ttAdapter()
});
$("#company_search").typeahead({
  items: 6,
  source:numbers.ttAdapter()
});
$("#position_search").typeahead({
  items: 6,
  source:numbers.ttAdapter()
});
```

with

```
var array = ["#nav_search", "#company_search", "#position_search"]
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $(array[i]).typehead({
        items: 6,
        souce: numbers.ttAdapter()
    });
}
```

if I'm not wrong, here `AJAX` is included. So they are doing a `GET` request to your backend url `/autocomplete`

```
  remote: {
    url: "autocomplete?search=%QUERY",
    wildcard: "%QUERY"
  }
```

You need to check your Rails `routes.rb` file and the output from `rake routes`, because the request `get /autocomplete` will be handled with a specific controller#action. You need to understand this from `rails routing`

The get request at url `/autocomplete` is passing the following input parameters

```
search = %QUERY
```

so you controller action will be able to use those parameters.

```
parameters[:search]
```

and it will respond to provide the autocomplete with json.

We need more info if you want to get more help

Comment: In this way, how to differentiate these three inputs? eg when I write something as input for company, I hope to do evoke the call like autocomplete/company?search=%QUERY, so the controller will know I only need autocomplete for company not for other parts.

Comment: [updated] In this way, how to differentiate these three inputs? eg1. when I write something as input for company, I hope the controller return information only related to company not for other information. eg2. when I write something as input for navigation, I hope the controller will know I need autocomplete for all kinds of information. I think I need to specify a part in the url like autocomplete?type=%type?search=%QUERY, so the controller can know which value to return according to type and I only need only route for /autocomplete, but I don't know how to do this in the ajax part.

Comment: @makeapp you are saying that you want to pass an additional parameter to the backend? yes, that may not be the best code solution but it would work. They will be in the params hash in the backend. the only thing.. I don't have a clear undestanding of the library you are using for building this

Comment: I am using typeahead.js, rails4 and searchkick(for elasticsearch).